# Calculate the ERC165 interfaceId of any contract type manually

Tags: web3js, erc165

I have a contract whose interface has been registered using ERC165

Within solidity, it's easy to retrieve the `interfaceId` for any contract type by doing `type({registeredInterface}).interfaceId`

But what if I want an external application to check for a contract type? I need to first calculate the `interfaceId` and then pass the `interfaceId` to `supportsInterface()` on the contract.

For example, I want to call `supportsInterface()` on [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fac1708810768a96858a92fd220e5d74e97e584#readContract) for `IERC721Delegable`

How do I do that outside of solidity if I don't know the `interfaceId` of `IERC721Delegable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, look up the code for the interface you're trying to calculate the `interfaceId` for.

In my case it was this interface: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fac1708810768a96858a92fd220e5d74e97e584#code#F3#L1

That interface has 5 functions:
`event DelegateTokenSet()`
`function setDelegateToken()`
`function setDelegateToken()`
`function getDelgateToken()`
`function approveByDelegate()`

First, DROP all events, you won't need them. You just need the functions.

Now, calculate the Keccak256 hash for each of the functions, including their argument types (exclude the argument names), so you should have

```
setDelegateToken(address,uint256,uint256) //638235a4
setDelegateToken(address,uint256,uint256,bytes) //2f00af51
getDelegateToken(uint256) //c4be7597
approveByDelegate(address,uint256)//8b7e4caa
```

Then, take each of the hashes and run it through an XOR function. When you XOR an array of items, you're running XOR on 1 and 2 to get result A, then you XOR A and 3 to get result B, then you XOR B and 3 etc

So in my case:

```
638235a4 ^ 2f00af51 = 4c829af5
4c829af5 ^ c4be7597 = 883cef62
883cef62 ^ 8b7e4caa = 342a3c8
```

I used this online XOR calculator ==> https://xor.pw/#

Notice that `342a3c8` only has 7 characters. If it has less than 8, add a 0 in front. So `0342a3c8`. Then add a 0x in front to get `0x0342a3c8`

So you should have a 4 byte number (8 characters)

Now I take `0x0342a3c8` and put it in the `supportsInterface()` function of [my contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4fac1708810768a96858a92fd220e5d74e97e584#readContract)

And voilá! Get a `true` response

[image]